# Change phpmailer's FROM address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

How is phpmailer's FROM address changed?  I expected the following to work, however, all emails sent use the the send from email address set by the first occurrence of `SetFrom()`.

```
$mail = new myPHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug=2;

$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->MsgHTML('My Message');
$mail->AddReplyTo('me@myworkcompany.com');

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->SetFrom('me@myworkcompany.com');
$mail->AddAddress("someoneelse@otherdomain.com");
$mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->SetFrom('default@mydomain.com');  //Does not update FROM address!
$mail->AddAddress("someoneelse@myworkcompany.com");
$mail->Send();
```

PS.  Why I wish to do this?  I have found that some companies set up their e-mail routers to deny all incoming external emails which have a sender email top level domain the same as their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property Sender is set once when calling the method setFrom. There is no method to individually set Sender. However you can use

```
$mail->Sender = <newvaluehere>;
```

or

```
$mail->set('Sender', <NEWVALUEHERE>);
```

Also I'd like to advice against using this library,  it's hardly consistent nor does it seem production ready. You might consider a proven package like swiftmailer.

Reason why this class does not seem production ready

```
/**
 * Set or reset instance properties.
 * You should avoid this function - it's more verbose, less efficient, more error-prone and
 * harder to debug than setting properties directly.
 * Usage Example:
 * `$mail->set('SMTPSecure', 'tls');`
 *   is the same as:
 * `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`
 * @access public
 * @param string $name The property name to set
 * @param mixed $value The value to set the property to
 * @return boolean
 * @TODO Should this not be using the __set() magic function?
 */
```

Comment: Comment 1: Thanks for confirming what I observed.  I'll check out your other approach, and hopefully it works.  Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Comment 2: swiftmailer?  Like it?  Thought phpmailer was the defacto standard.  Always surprised that there isn't an real PHP embedded solution for modern email.  Maybe there is now?

Comment: I'd second the recommendation for SwiftMailer... its vastly superior and if anything is the standard nowadays I would say SwiftMailer is... I also do think there are any new extensions for mail. If there are they are in PECL and you would need to be able to install PECL extensions on the deployment target, which could be problematic if you get ham-stringed with some shared hosting.

Comment: Thanks Luceous.  Your solution works, however, One must first call `$mail->SetFrom('me@myworkcompany.com');` before (or maybe also after) doing so.